# How to italicize part of a word in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I would like few characters within a single word to be italicised in asciidoc

I tried using

```
with_emphasis_
```

But asciidoc does not interpret this. Is there a way to emphasise just the characters within the above word without separating them into separate words in asciidoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use "unconstrained" markup for partial word emphasis:

```
with__emphasis__
```

See: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#when-should-i-use-unconstrained-quotes